# Remove grid line in tableView

Tags: css, javafx-2, javafx, tableview, gridlines

I am trying to remove the grid line inside table view of each cell using css. 
[image]

For example, between the Name and Description column, there is a line which I assumed that it is grid line. I have no idea to remove it using css. I can do it in Java Swing using setShowGrid(false); but this does not available in javaFX.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you're asking about JavaFX 2. If not, I suggest you upgrade :)

Try putting this in your stylesheet:

```
.table-view {
  -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
}
```

Or call

```
tableObject.setStyle("-fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;")
```

In order to keep horizontal lines, I had to do the following

```
.table-view .table-row-cell {
  -fx-border-width: 1;
}
```

There's probably a better way to do this, but this worked for me...

Comment: But do you know how to hide the table header?

Comment: It works for the nominal case, but I still have the lines for the selected rows (focused or not).

Answer (score 1):

to remove grid line in tableView what @kylejmcintyre said is true.

to hide the table  header do this:

```
.column-header-background { visibility: hidden; -fx-padding: -1em; }
```