# Remove grid line in JavaFX TableView when cell is focused [that cyan one]

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview

I want to change the color of that cyan lines of `TableView` cell when they are focused , i have managed until now to modify the whole `TableView` with `css` but this one seems to be black magic which i can't find how to change.
[image]

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403875/remove-grid-line-in-tableview) question though it removes the grid line only when the cells are not focused .

---

Below is the css for anyone who want to have this style :) :

```
.table-view{
   -fx-background-color: #202020;
   -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
}

.table-view:focused{
    /*-fx-background-color: transparent;*/
}


.table-view .column-header {
     -fx-background-color: transparent;
     -fx-border-color:transparent white transparent transparent;
     -fx-border-width:0.1;
} 

.table-view .column-header-background{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#131313 0.0%, #424141 100.0%);
}

.table-view .column-header-background .label{
    -fx-background-color: transparent; 
    -fx-font-weight:bold;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.table-view .table-column{
    -fx-alignment:center;
}


/* .table-row-cell */

.table-row-cell:disabled{
    -fx-opacity:0.5;
    -fx-background-color:darkgray;    
}

.table-row-cell:disabled .text{
    /*-fx-strikethrough:  true ;*/
} 

.table-row-cell .text{
    -fx-font-weight:bold;
    -fx-fill: white ;
} 

/*.table-row-cell:focused .text {
     -fx-fill: white ;
} */

.table-row-cell:hover .text , .table-row-cell:selected .text{
     -fx-fill: white ;    
}

.table-row-cell:hover:selected .text,.table-row-cell:focused:selected .text{
    -fx-fill:rgb(173.0,255.0,10.0);
}


/*.table-row-cell:focused{
    -fx-background-color:firebrick;
}*/

.table-row-cell:focused:disabled{ 
    -fx-background-color:darkgray;
}

.table-row-cell:hover , .table-row-cell:selected{
    /*-fx-background-color:rgb(0.0,191.0,255.0);*/
     -fx-background-color:firebrick;
}


.table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: #202020;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0, 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This troubled me as well.

```
.table-row-cell{ 
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
}
```

This should do the job.